# Converting quaternions to angles for a 3D editor

Tags: c#, math, game-physics, game-development, quaternions

I have a 3D map editor and the objects are rotated using a quaternion, but also the user has the ability to set angles using a textbox. I need to correctly convert from angles to quaternion and back

I tried using Euler angles, but they have singularity issues. Y has a limit from -90 to 90, which is extremely inconvenient. What methods are there to control the rotation of an object so that the user can change specific degrees of angle. How is this done in Unreal engine, unity?

Here is the code I am using now

```
double sinr_cosp = 2 * (q.W * q.X + q.Y * q.Z);
double cosr_cosp = 1 - 2 * (q.X * q.X + q.Y * q.Y);
double Xn = System.Math.Atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp);

//pitch / y
double Yn;
double sinp = 2 * (q.W * q.Y - q.Z * q.X);
if (System.Math.Abs(sinp) >= 1)
{
    Yn = System.Math.PI / 2 * (float)System.Math.Sign(sinp);
}
else
{
    Yn = System.Math.Asin(sinp);
}

//yaw / z
double siny_cosp = 2 * (q.W * q.Z + q.X * q.Y);
double cosy_cosp = 1 - 2 * (q.Y * q.Y + q.Z * q.Z);
double Zn = System.Math.Atan2(siny_cosp, cosy_cosp);
```

Comment: You can check out my library, has to and from for euler angles: https://github.com/probablytukars/LuaQuaternion . Here is my source as well https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/index.htm . Can't write a full answer on my phone at the minute. Includes all six possible combinations of euler conversions.